# react-native-copilot not working with class based component, What exact mechanism this library use in class base component

Tags: react-native, tooltip

When we create demo project it's working fine but when we add this code in our application live project that time this code is not working?

I previously try create demo react native application and this library use in class base component but when my live project i add this code it's not working. please share class base component withi this library code example or code snippest.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hey! I'm the creator of react-native-copilot. I recently published v3 and updated the README. Hope that would help you rectify the issue.